# iOS : Setting actions, datasources and delegates not to the file's owner

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, interface-builder, datasource

Maybe those are two different questions, but they basically ask the same thing.
I have a single view app, on my screen I have a `Table View` and a `Collection View`. 
1) I want to provide a `datasource` (and `delegate` of course) for my tableview and for my collection view, but I don't want it to be in the same (main) `ViewController` file (in purpose of cleaner code). But the interface builder only allows me declaring as `datasource` (and `delegate`) the file's owner, which is the view controller. How can I do this? Is declaring programatically the right way? If so, where should it be done? Or, maybe, separating the datasources (and delegates) from the `ViewController` isn't the best practice?
2) In my table view's custom cells I have a button I wan't to deal with the button's actions in the same place (file) I deal with row selection (delegate obj). But once again the IB only let's me to connect the action to the custom cell class. How can I connect the action to another place?

Thank you for your answers in advance, 
Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the Object (the blue cube) from the object library. Drag and drop to the section (Documents outline) where your file's owner is present. Then in the identity inspector set it as the class (say `Outsider`) you want it to be. This will allow you to set `Outsider` object as the delegate/datasource and will also allow you to write `IBAction`'s there. 
The trick is to make that object(Class) visible in the xib by creating an object inside the xib (which will be done when the nib is loaded ).

And another thing, there is nothing wrong in setting the delegate or datasource programmatically, however through interface builder its much more convenient.

Comment: Thank you this is a great solution. I've never said that doing this programatically is bad. I come from the world of Android, and there I've never used a toll such as Interface builder, only code, that's why Im a bit confused about it's capabilities :)

Comment: Okey. Even I used to resort to code to do things which I could have done through the IB. But later on realized its much more convenient through IB.  :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Do it programatically. Write your own delegate and assign it in code. Cleaner.

2) Connect the button's action in the ViewController class. That is clean, that's what view controllers are meant for. Turn on assistant editor and drag the "arrow" to the header file.

Comment: 1) Where should I perform the assignment? at the `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: 2) The action that the button performs is logically simillar to selections of the entire row, that's why I wan't to include them both in the same class, Is there a way to do it?

Comment: That would be fine...though I think it is deprecated, so you could use `viewWillAppear` also...

Comment: The selection and the button press should be done in the view controller. That is where you should place both IBActions.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is not deprecated. Its `viewDidUnload` thats deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

> But the interface builder only allows me declaring as datasource (and
>   delegate) the file's owner, which is the view controller.

Question 2:

> But once again the IB only let's me to connect the action to the
>   custom cell class. How can I connect the action to another place?

Both have same answer:

You can change the class by selectecing from interface builder.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to change it's classes I just want to assign the datasource (and delegate) and the buttons action to a different class

Comment: You are going against the design pattern. MVC you are going to share Controller on multiple files but not fully.

Comment: @anoop: can you elaborate? Isn't it better if i have a separate controller for the different views in my super view. Rather than making a controller class very big, isn't it better to split it up?

Comment: Sometimes. But in a given view for 3 buttons some class as delegate for 2 buttons some other, for tableview someother. Isn't it a mess of Controller around you? Make it simple.